# psycopg2 vs sys.stdin.read()

Tags: psycopg2

I have small code like below :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import psycopg2, sys

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='smdr' user='bino'");
except:
    print "I am unable to connect to the database"
cur = conn.cursor()
v_num = '1'  
cur.execute("SELECT * from genctr WHERE code = %(num)s", dict(num=v_num))
rows = cur.fetchall()
print "\nShow me the databases:\n"
ctrnum =0
for row in rows:
    print row[0]+","+row[1]
```

when i run it, i got

```
bino@erp:~/mydoc/openerp/smdr$ ./genctr.py 

Show me the databases:

1,Bahamas
1,Barbados
1,Canada
1,Cayman Islands
1,United States
1,Virgin Islands U.S.
```

I try to replace "v_num = '1' " with "v_num = sys.stdin.read()"

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import psycopg2, sys

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='smdr' user='bino'");
except:
    print "I am unable to connect to the database"
cur = conn.cursor()
#v_num = '1'
v_num = sys.stdin.read()
cur.execute("SELECT * from genctr WHERE code = %(num)s", dict(num=v_num))
rows = cur.fetchall()
print "\nShow me the databases:\n"
ctrnum =0
for row in rows:
    print row[0]+","+row[1]
```

But when I run it , I only got this :

```
bino@erp:~/mydoc/openerp/smdr$ echo 1 |./genctr.py 

Show me the databases:
```

Kindly please give me your enlightment on how to fix it

Sincerely

-bino-

Answer (score 1):

`echo 1` is going to give "1\n" to your program (that is, "1" with a newline character afterward).  `sys.stdin.read()` is going to return that exact string, and then psycopg2 is going to prepare the SQL statement as `SELECT * from genctr WHERE code = '1\n'`.  The result is going to be no matching results, so the code inside the for loop will never execute, which is why you don't see any extra output.

Try doing either `echo -n 1` to suppress the newline, or `sys.stdin.read().strip()` to remove any leading and trailing whitespace from the string.  If the `code` field is an integer, it might be a good idea to cast the result of `sys.stdin.read()` to an int, too, like so:

```
int(sys.stdin.read().strip())
```

Comment: Dear Zach Hirsch

Thankyou for your enlightment
It work like a charm

Sincerely
-bino-